# Have div display ONLY on first time visit (cookies?)

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm trying to have a div display on the very first time a user visits my site. I'm pretty sure I do this by using cookies, which I have limited experience with and am have a hard time understanding. Most tutorials I've found online only talk about having cookies prompt a user to input something like a name, and have it recall it later, which not what I want at all. I simply want the cookie to check if the user has been to my site before, and if not, display a div that is normally hidden.

Here's something I've tried and failed to get to work.

HTML:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="annoy.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>

...
<body>
    <div id="overbox3">
         <div id="infobox3">
              <p>This is the cookie box</p>
              <br />
              <p>it should only show once </p>
              <br/><br/>
         </div><!-- end infobox3 --> 
    </div> <!-- end overbox3 -->
</body>
```

CSS (not really relevant since this works fine):

```
#overbox3 {
         position: fixed;
         top: 0px;
         left: 0px;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%; 
         background: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5);
         z-index: 999999;
         display: none;
    }

    #infobox3 {
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 35%;
        top: 20%;
        height: 300px;
         width: 400px;
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

Relevant content of scripts.js:

```
function popbox3() {
    $('#overbox3').toggle();
}
```

And what I assume is the problem, the content of annoy.js:

```
    function GetCookie(name) {
        var arg=name+"=";
        var alen=arg.length;
        var clen=document.cookie.length;
        var i=0;

        while (i<clen) {
            var j=i+alen;
                if (document.cookie.substring(i,j)==arg)
                    return "here";
                i=document.cookie.indexOf(" ",i)+1;
                if (i==0) 
                    break;
        }

        return null;
    }

    var visit=GetCookie("COOKIE1");

    if (visit==null){
    var expire=new Date();

    popbox3();

    expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+7776000000);
    document.cookie="COOKIE1=here; expires="+expire;
}
```

From my understanding, the cookie is supposed to be calling the function popbox3() only if the user has not visited, which would toggle the display of the hidden div. But as of now, nothing is working. Any clarification or help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what happens if I visit and delete my cookies?

Comment: An alternative would be to use [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) to track this. Nicer api/less overhead than cookies.

Comment: @RUJordan I should have clarified that I don't mind that. If someone clears their cookies, I have no problem with the div displaying again.

Comment: @NickTomlin after looking through the readme and watching the screencast for store.js, I'm not sure I really understand how I could use it for this problem? It seems like with it, I have to manually input values for it to store. Could you elaborate a bit on how I could use it to detect if a user has been to my site, and execute a function if that's not the case?

Comment: Try to get the cookie. If it's not found it's the user's first visit, so run the function and set the cookie. If it's found, they're a repeat visitor, just set the cookie again (to update its expiration date).

Comment: Are you running your code in `$(document).ready()`? If not, you're toggling the DIV before it has been loaded in the first place. Your cookie code looks fine.

Comment: @Barmar That was indeed the problem. A stupid mistake on my part, but now I know. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your cookie code looks fine. You need to run it in the document ready handler, so that it waits until the document is loaded before toggling the DIV:

```
$(function() {
    var visit=GetCookie("COOKIE1");

    if (visit==null){
        popbox3();
    }
    var expire=new Date();
    expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+7776000000);
    document.cookie="COOKIE1=here; expires="+expire;
}
```

I've also made setting the cookie unconditional, so that every visit to the site will push back the expiration time.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. To clarify, this code would be a replacement only for everything under the return null;} in my original annoy.js, correct?

Comment: Yes. Although you could put the functions inside it if you wish, to keep them from polluting the global namespace.

Comment: I have to? I help you once, now I'm your slave for life?