# how to set cookie for display notification bar at only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I had set notification on my site,

This is the jquery for notification bar:

```
function showNotification(params){
    // options array
    var options = { 
        'showAfter': 0, // number of sec to wait after page loads
        'duration': 0, // display duration
        'autoClose' : false, // flag to autoClose notification message
        'type' : 'success', // type of info message error/success/info/warning
        'message': '', // message to dispaly
        'link_notification' : '', // link flag to show extra description
        'description' : '' // link to desciption to display on clicking link message
    }; 
    // Extending array from params
    $.extend(true, options, params);

    var msgclass = 'succ_bg'; // default success message will shown
    if(options['type'] == 'error'){
        msgclass = 'error_bg'; // over write the message to error message
    } else if(options['type'] == 'information'){
        msgclass = 'info_bg'; // over write the message to information message
    } else if(options['type'] == 'warning'){
        msgclass = 'warn_bg'; // over write the message to warning message
    } 

    // Parent Div container
    var container = '<div id="info_message" class="'+msgclass+'"><div class="center_auto"><div class="info_message_text message_area">';
    container += options['message'];
    container += '</div><div class="info_close_btn button_area" onclick="return closeNotification()"></div><div class="clearboth"></div>';
    container += '</div><div class="info_more_descrption"></div></div>';

    $notification = $(container);

    // Appeding notification to Body
    $('body').append($notification);

    var divHeight = $('div#info_message').height();
    // see CSS top to minus of div height
    $('div#info_message').css({
        top : '-'+divHeight+'px'
    });

    // showing notification message, default it will be hidden
    $('div#info_message').show();

    // Slide Down notification message after startAfter seconds
    slideDownNotification(options['showAfter'], options['autoClose'],options['duration']);

    $('.link_notification').live('click', function(){
        $('.info_more_descrption').html(options['description']).slideDown('fast');
    });

}
// function to close notification message
// slideUp the message
function closeNotification(duration){
    var divHeight = $('div#info_message').height();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('div#info_message').animate({
            top: '-'+divHeight
        }); 
        // removing the notification from body
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('div#info_message').remove();
        },200);
    }, parseInt(duration * 3000));   

}

// sliding down the notification
function slideDownNotification(startAfter, autoClose, duration){    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('div#info_message').animate({
            top: 0
        }); 
        if(autoClose){
            setTimeout(function(){
                closeNotification(duration);
            }, duration);
        }
    }, parseInt(startAfter * 5000));    
}
```

This is the code i added in index page:

```
<script >
          function showAutoCloseMessage(){
             showNotification({
      message: "You cart total must be at least $200 for free shipping",
          autoClose: true,
          duration: 2
          });             
     }       
     $(document).ready(function() {
           showAutoCloseMessage();
       });                             
     </script>
```

Now i need to set cookies for this. I need, when user enter the website, that time only show notification bar, after that don't show. I mean, when user reload the site don't show the notification bar.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps session storage will do the trick: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_session in the example there is a clickCount variable, but you could use boolean type as well for example: hasPageLoaded -> true or false

Comment: [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904697/have-div-display-only-on-first-time-visit-cookies)

Comment: @anpsmn: but.. i am working liquid code.. this code is totally different from me.. how can i fix this?

Comment: You have pasted js above. The link has solution in js. Check if a cookie eg. `first` exists and if it doesn't exist set a cookie with an expiry date and call your showNotification().

Comment: @selva [try this](http://pastebin.com/QT69Tz43)

Comment: @anpsmn: that didn't open...

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/etL8pc23/). PS: Not a demo just copied the js code as pastebin is not working for you.

Comment: @anpsmn: this is the link.. http://jsfiddle.net/etL8pc23/1/.. i used these code only.. https://develite.myshopify.com/ is my website.

Comment: @anpsmn: still i didn't get..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68071/discussion-between-selva-and-anpsmn).

Comment: @anpsmn: can you please see this link http://jsfiddle.net/t90096vs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)
and put the condition,

```
if ($.cookie('setCookie') == null) {
...
}
```

Comment: sorry. i can't able to understand.. i am newer.

Comment: whereever you want :) set te library and $(document).ready(function() { if ($.cookie('setCookie') == null) { $.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7 }); [your function] })

Comment: it is only lifetime if 7 days is too short for you yo can put sth else