# How to set cookies foe notification bar

Tags: jquery, cookies

I had a code for notification bar, I need , when user run the page at first time, it will show notification bar, when the user refresh the page it won't show.

this is code i used,

```
<div id="page-wrap">

    <div id="note">
        You smell good. <a id="close">[close]</a>
    </div>

    <h1>Pop From Top Message</h1>

    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis </p>

    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
 <script>
   close = document.getElementById("close");
   close.addEventListener('click', function() {
     note = document.getElementById("note");
     note.style.display = 'none';
   }, false);
  </script>
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t90096vs/

How can i add cookie to fix this.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question you asked a year ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904697/have-div-display-only-on-first-time-visit-cookies/18905120?noredirect=1#comment43895168_18905120 shows how to test if it's the first time on a site. Why can't you use the same technique?

Comment: That was over a year ago, shouldn't you be more experienced? How long does it take you to learn how to program?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    function GetCookie(name) {
        var arg=name+"=";
        var alen=arg.length;
        var clen=document.cookie.length;
        var i=0;

        while (i<clen) {
            var j=i+alen;
                if (document.cookie.substring(i,j)==arg)
                    return "here";
                i=document.cookie.indexOf(" ",i)+1;
                if (i==0) 
                    break;
        }

        return null;
    }
    var visit = GetCookie("showed_note");
    if (visit == null) {
        $("#note").show();
        document.cookie = "showed_note=true";
    } else {
        $("#note").hide();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/t90096vs/7/)

Comment: may i know, where i can add ?

Comment: Put it in your `<script>` block.

Comment: I have added your code.. but still stays same.. i have checked to add in index.html and modernizr.custom.80028.js.

Comment: Change `#notification` to the actual ID of your notification bar. I just put that in as a placeholder.

Comment: still it didn't work @barmar. have you look at my jsfiddle? thanks

Comment: Do you have an updated fiddle that shows what you tried?

Comment: You didn't load jQuery in the fiddle. Also, you should put the Javascript in the bottom left box, the top left box if for HTML.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t90096vs/3/ this updated, where i can added in bottom left, but it didn't work.

Comment: can you please provide your answer with jsfiddle?

Comment: I was missing a `}`. And your fiddle still wasn't loading jQuery from the Frameworks menu, and you didn't copy the `GetCookie()` function. I've linked to my fiddle in the answer.

Comment: are you there @barmar

Comment: when run the script by new user it show notification or not?

Comment: The first time it shows the notification. When you refresh or come back later, it doesn't.