# how to pop up a Notice Span when user just log in (but not just refresh to the home page)?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, session, cookies

I do not know how to detect it is the first time that user login the web.

I thought i should write a pop-up span on the jsp that user firstly saw when he login.but the issue is then he refresh the page,the notic will show again,that is ridiculous. 
**I need detect if it is first login means to detect if the user JUST LOGIN or NOT REFRESH the page**

how and where shall I detect if it is the first time user login ? and then i can make mind if the notice span pop up.

and I think it should use cookies or session,but which one should i use?

Comment: You'll need to check for a cookie, if it's present, don't show the popup. If it isn't, add a cookie and show the popup. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904697/have-div-display-only-on-first-time-visit-cookies

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Java?

Comment: hope not ..if the logic should be written in java-end,it may be more complicate

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a field in database table that check if it is first login than show a popup and after that change the value of that field so that Popup do not appear next time.

Ex:

```
if($data['first_login'] == 1)

    {
        // show popup
    }
```

Comment: I need detect if it is first login means to detect if the user JUST LOGIN or NOT REFRESH the page.sorry My poor English.

Comment: For this make an extra check if the login credential are OK then before settings the session "It is a first login". Use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show it only to the new user (the time user registers) you can use a table column in database where you can use it to check if the user if logging in for the first time (e.g firtsLogin the column name = 1 ). If he is logging in for the first time you show the pop-up and change the value of the field to 0.

Otherwise if you want to show to users that are logged in to a specific device for the first time you should use cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to detect the user logging in to your web-site the first time. There are multiple ways that you can do it depending on your desire to spend additional time writing the code, the location of your logging-in logic (client or server side), security that you want to have while proving your users with login functionality. In all cases - you would have to store the data whether the user has logged in for the first time. I think you are seeking a fast solution that will work without a big care for privacy or security as working with client-side cookies isn't the safest way to store data. The alternatives to cookies are web tokens, url query string, server-side sessions and data-base (RDBMS) storage.

Storing and retrieving the data on the client-side using [**COOKIES**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). They are the pieces stored in the user's web browser. Cookies were created to help servers remember the data about the user next time he enters the web-site. The most common usages are: to store location (if accepted by user), web-site locale (language in which the user was browsing the site), products added to cart, etc. Following that approach you can create cookie after the user has logged in to your web-site as follows:

This should be run by your JavaScript.

```
document.cookie = "firstLogin=true";
```

After having done that, you would have to add JavaScript logic that will hook-up to user's/client's COOKIE data and read up whether he has logged in the first time before.

This would probably look like a simple JavaScript cookie look-up.

```
var cookieData = document.cookie;
```

This will return all of your user's cookies that has been previously stored when he visited your web-site. It will return it as a string concatenated with "; ". If we had previously stored only one cookie, we would get `firstLogin=true;`

In case if you have multiple cookies set before, you would have to parse the cookie string and extract the data either imperatively by plain procedural JavaScript code or by writing the function which will be able to do that repeatedly. Detailed examples of writing such functions could be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).